# Angular 2: Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

Im trying to integrate ng2-file-upload module into my application.

And im getting this template error: Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

**UPDATE folder str:**

```
/src/app/app.module.ts

/src/app/components/layout/
                           layout.module.ts
                           other layout components files

                  /category-items
                            category-items.module.ts
                            category-items.component.ts
```

**in layout.module.ts**

```
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';

declarations: [
    LayoutComponent,
```

**in category-items.module.ts**

```
import { CategoryItemsComponent } from './category-items.component';

import {FileUploadModule} from "ng2-file-upload";   

imports: [  ...FileUploadModule ... ]
```

**app\app.module.ts**

```
 import {FileUploadModule} from "ng2-file-upload";   

 imports: [  ...FileUploadModule ... ]
```

**app\components\layout\category-items\category-items.component.ts**

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-view',
  template: `

  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="single" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />   

  `
  })

export class ButtonViewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {

...
 public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url:'http://lcoalhost:5000/upload'});

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-items',
  templateUrl: './category-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-items.component.scss']
})

export class CategoryItemsComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

Or if i try out like below: i get unexpected closing div tag

```
<div ng2FileDrop
         (fileOver)-'fileOverBase($event)'
         [uploader]="uploader"
         class="well my-drop-zone">
        Base drop zone
    </div>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of imports for **'FileUploadModule'** in my app.module in various posts, but none seems to work in my case.

**Error Stack trace:**

> "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("↵ ↵

Have googled many posts for solutions for the same:

Some of the references were: (but none helping)

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/418

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/608

Comment: did you import the `FileUploadModule` in the same module as the `CategoryItemsComponent`? Ie: is the `CategoryItemsComponent` declared **only** in the app.module.ts?

Comment: have updated my folder str, could you please tell what i am missing or what i should verify?

Comment: I suspect you haven't imported the module into the correct module - category-items.module.ts could you paste it so that I can verify

Comment: oh man, i got it ...thanks for the remainder, i had to import FileUploadModule under category-items.module.ts

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then for future users

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to import `FileUploadModule` in the module that declares the component using `'upload'` which in your case would be `category-items.module.ts`

**category-items.module.ts**

```js
import { CategoryItemsComponent } from './category-items.component';

import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";   //Should import HERE

imports: [  ...FileUploadModule ... ]   //RIGHT PLACE
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with working answer!

Comment: perhaps it would be better for future users reading the question, trying to match it to their own situation if the answer is not also in the question? you could post the component as it was before you fixed it and I could show the fixed version here

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Ompurdy, have reverted my question ...you can also mention in your answer the place i had imported before and after correction

Comment: @phyme It will not matter that you **also** had it imported there so I won't recommend removing it in case someone else has a need for it to also be imported there.

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for. The documentation needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks, it's a miss in documentation

Comment: Also make sure you placed the AppRoutingModule to the last in the app.module.ts 
imports[]

@NgModule({
imports: [ 
...
FileUploadModule,
AppRoutingModule // must be imported as the last module as it contains the fallback route
...
]

Answer (score 3):

**add to app.module.ts this**

```
import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
],
    declarations: [
        FileSelectDirective
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
],
    bootstrap: [
        App,
    ],
})
```

**https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/418#issuecomment-249865170**

**Or try to import FIleUploadModule to an each parent module**

import { FIleUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';

```
imports: [
    FIleUploadModule,
    ..........,
    ........,
    ......,

]
```

**It should work.**