# angular 5 - ng2-file-upload: Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, ng-file-upload, angular5, angular-template

**I read previous questions and the solutions to the answers were already in place, which is why I started another question**

I get the following error with ng2-file-upload in Angular 5:

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("s': hasAnotherDropZoneOver}"
                 (fileOver)="fileOverAnother($event)"
                 [ERROR ->][uploader]="uploader"
                 class="well my-drop-zone">
                Another drop zone
"): ng:///AppModule/UploadComponent.html@25:17
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24312)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:33699)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:33674)
    at eval (compiler.js:33576)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:33576)
    at eval (compiler.js:33446)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:455)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33445)
```

I imported and declared the directive into my `app.module.ts` and the error persisted. Has anyone had this issue with **ng-file-upload** and angular 5?

Comment: Do you have `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],` in your main `@NgModule`?

Comment: @msanford yeah, i do. I actually figured it out. see the answer below. it won't let me mark it as answered though. I literally just figured it out after i posted it.

Comment: Sweet! Yeah you have to come back in a few days to accept it, but please do once the timer expires.

Comment: @msanford definitely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileUploadModule` needs to be imported and added to imports in the module declaring the component.

```
import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";   //Should import HERE

imports: [  ...FileUploadModule ... ]   //RIGHT PLACE
```

[Angular 2: Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303404/angular-2-cant-bind-to-uploader-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input?noredirect=1#comment77574329_45303404)

Comment: You changed it from a parameter binding to an event binding? And that actually works? I don't know anything about ng-uploader but that seems super weird to me, since those two things (obviously) work in opposite 'directions'. Any idea what the core problem was?

Comment: huh? property binding to event binding works for you?

Answer (score 0):

**In the respective module.ts file add**

```
import { FileUploadModule  } from 'ng2-file-upload';

Add it under import 
  @NgModule({
      imports: [
         FileUploadModule
      ]
})

<b>Import FileUploaderOptions,FileUploader into your .ts file </b>

      import { FileUploaderOptions,FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
```

**In this class .ts file, add entries**

```
  options: FileUploaderOptions;
  uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader(this.options);

<b>In the ngOnInit() add the text </b>

    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
        console.log('file:uploaded:', item, status, response);
        alert('File uploaded successfully');
    }
```

**In the HTML file add the select button**

```
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect  [uploader]="uploader" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" 
          (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" 
          [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length" >
              Upload file
        </button>
      </div>
```