# 'ng2-file-upload' error in Angular 6- Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, file-upload, mean-stack, ng2-file-upload

I am developing a web application using Angular 6. This is my folder structure.
app
 |
 pages
   |
   dashboard
          |
         maps

In maps component I am uploading files using 'ng2-file-upload'.
This is my 'maps.component.html'

```
 <form #mapsForm="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="mapName" class="form-control" name="mapName"  >
        </div>

        <br>

        <label for="geoRefMap">Geo- reference Map</label>
        <div class="input-group">

         <input type="file"  #fileInput name="milespec"  
         class="form-control"
         ng2FileSelect
         [uploader]="uploader" 
         (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" />
          <img src="../../../../../assets/images/maps/Browse.png" width="40" height="40" style=" position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px"  onclick="openfileDialog();"/>
        </div>
        <br>
    </form>
```

I used 'FileUploader' in maps.component.ts file.

```
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective  } from 'ng2-file-upload';

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
}
```

But it gives me the following error.

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
>          class="form-control"
>          ng2FileSelect 
>          [ERROR ->][uploader]="uploader" 
>          (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" />
>           <!-- <in"): ng:///DashboardModule/MapsComponent.html@23:9
> Error: Template parse errors:
> ```

I tried several solutions here 'https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/418' But did not work. I tried adding 'FileSelectDirective' into all the parents modules time to time. But did not work. Does any one has any solution?

Comment: This thread might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45303404/8365253

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. All I have to do is in my **app.module.ts** (or your sub module), add

```
 declarations: [
     ...
     FileSelectDirective
  ],
```